# org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction;

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working with Spring 4.2.0 and Hibernate 4.0.1 and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:436)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy19.getUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.scm.Service.scmServiceImpl.getUser(scmServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.scm.Controller.myHomeController.CheckLogin(myHomeController.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my controller is:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.scm.Beans.Users;
import com.scm.Service.scmService;


@Controller
public class myHomeController {

    @Autowired
    private scmService scm_service;

    public scmService getScm_service() {
        return scm_service;
    }

    public void setScm_service(scmService scm_service) {
        this.scm_service = scm_service;
    }


    HttpSession session;

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(HttpSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

---

Service Implementation class:

```
@Service
public class scmServiceImpl implements scmService {

    @Autowired
    private scmDao scmdao;

    public scmDao getScmdao() {
        return scmdao;
    }

    public void setScmdao(scmDao scmdao) {
        this.scmdao = scmdao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> getUser(String username) {   
        return scmdao.getUser(username);
    }
}
```

---

This is the DAO I'm using:

```
@Repository("scmDao")
public class scmDaoImpl implements scmDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

---

My dispatcher-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.scm" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" /> 

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/SCM1" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres123"/>
    </bean> 


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: any pom files ?

Comment: @georgesvan, I have updated my question, I am not using pom

Answer (score 0):

The logs indicate

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session; at
```

My best guess would be due to a version mismatch between your spring and hiberante 
Look at your spring ORM dependencies , probably you are using an older version of hibernate. Check out 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.0.RELEASE
to find the exact dependencies. I suppose by upgrading your hibernate to 4.3.10.Final you should not see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception is throw when the application can not wiring to DB...

If you are not using pom.xml please try to create the path WEB-INF/lib and there you must add your postgres jar.
If you have it try with another version of jar for postgres...